# How to design a textfield like whatsapp in flutter

Tags: uitextfield, flutter-layout

I need the textfield should expand vertically up to 5 enter key pressed

after the 5th enter other lines are should enclose within the scrollbar

how can I achieve the textfield I need using flutter

now I set the maxlines: null in the textfield

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you guys for your suggestions but I have found the actual textfield by the below code

```
                 Flexible(
                          child: new ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                              minWidth: size.width,
                              maxWidth: size.width,
                              minHeight: 25.0,
                              maxHeight: 135.0,
                            ),
                            child: new Scrollbar(
                              child: new TextField(
                                cursorColor: Colors.red,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                maxLines: null,                                    
                                controller: tc,
                                _handleSubmitted : null,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 2.0,
                                      left: 13.0,
                                      right: 13.0,
                                      bottom: 2.0),
                                  hintText: "Type your message",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color:Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),                           
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by adding maxLine and minLine in TextField

```
new TextField(
             minLines: 1,
             maxLines: 5,

            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 5.0),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 5.0),
              ),
              hintText: 'Mobile Number',
            ),
          )
```